# Pagination not showing up in parsed content (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pagination

I am new to python programming and I have a problem with pagination while using beautiful soup. all the parsed content show up except the pagination contents. [image of content not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeON4.png) I have highlighted the lines which does not show up.
[Website link](https://www.yellowpages.lk/Medical.php).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html

url = "https://www.yellowpages.lk/Medical.php"

result = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "lxml")

time.sleep(5)

Table = doc.find('table',{'id':'MedicalFacility'}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
Page = doc.select('.col-lg-10')

C_List = []
D_List = []
N_List = []
A_List = []
T_List = []
W_List = []
V_List = []
M_List = []

print(doc.prettify())
print(Page)
while True:

    for i in range(0,25):
        Sort = Table[i]
        
        Category = Sort.find_all('td')[0].get_text().strip()
        C_List.insert(i,Category)
        
        District = Sort.find_all('td')[1].get_text().strip()
        D_List.insert(i,District)
        
        Name = Sort.find_all('td')[2].get_text().strip()
        N_List.insert(i,Name)
        
        Address = Sort.find_all('td')[3].get_text().strip()
        A_List.insert(i,Address)
        
        Telephone = Sort.find_all('td')[4].get_text().strip()
        T_List.insert(i,Telephone)
        
        Whatsapp = Sort.find_all('td')[5].get_text().strip()
        W_List.insert(i,Whatsapp)
        
        Viber = Sort.find_all('td')[6].get_text().strip()
        V_List.insert(i,Viber)

        MoH_Division = Sort.find_all('td')[7].get_text().strip()
        M_List.insert(i,MoH_Division)
```

I tried using .find() with class and .select('.class') to see if the pagination contents show up so far nothing has worked

Comment: It appears that the pagination is generated by javascript, which means you are pretty much out of luck using requests. I tried to look for requests via network but couldn't find anything of use. The only way you could successfully scrape it would be to use something like selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination is more or less superfluous in that page: the data is loaded anyway, and Javascript is generating pagination just for display purposes: Requests will get full data anyway.
Here is one way of getting that information in full:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.yellowpages.lk/Medical.php'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('table[id="MedicalFacility"]')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Category    District    Name    Address Telephone   WhatsApp    Viber   MoH Division
0   Pharmacy    Gampaha A & B Pharmacy  171 Negambo Road Veyangoda  0778081515  9.477808e+10    9.477808e+10    Aththanagalla
1   Pharmacy    Trincomalee A A Pharmacy    350 Main Street Kanthale    0755576998  9.475558e+10    9.475558e+10    Kanthale
2   Pharmacy    Colombo A Baur & Co Pvt Ltd 55 Grandpass Rd Col 14  0768200100  9.476820e+10    9.476820e+10    CMC
3   Pharmacy    Colombo A Colombo Pharmacy  Ug 93 97 Peoples Park Colombo 11    0773771446  9.477377e+10    NaN CMC
4   Pharmacy    Trincomalee A R Pharmacy    Main Street Kinniya-3   0771413838  9.477500e+10    9.477500e+10    Kinniya
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1968    Pharmacy    Ampara  Zam Zam Pharmacy    Main Street Akkaraipattu    0672277698  9.477756e+10    9.477756e+10    Akkaraipattu
1969    Pharmacy    Batticaloa  Zattra Pharmacy Jummah Mosque Rd Oddamawadi-1   0766689060  9.476669e+10    NaN Oddamavady
1970    Pharmacy    Puttalam    Zeenath Pharmacy    Norochcholei    0728431622  NaN NaN Kalpitiya
1971    Pharmacy    Puttalam    Zidha Pharmacy  Norochcholei    0773271222  NaN NaN Kalpitiya
1972    Pharmacy    Gampaha Zoomcare Pharmacy & Grocery 182/B/1 Rathdoluwa Seeduwa  0768378112  NaN NaN Seeduwa
1973 rows × 8 columns
```

See pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/). Also [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and lastly, [Requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **pandas**, all you need is just a couple of lines of code to put the **entire table** into a **dataframe**.

All you need is [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) function as follows:

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://www.yellowpages.lk/Medical.php")[0]

print(df)
```

#### Output:

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: Indeed, but if you will test your solution on 10 different IPs, you will notice a failure rate of over 70%. The proper way is to actually use a header to scrape the data.

Comment: This works well for the specific task at hand. If the task was to scrape data for 10 different IPs, then I would suggest your solution.

Comment: No mate, you are missing the point: web scraping capabilities built in pandas are basic, and tend to fail, not being able to fully mimic an organic, browser-like request.

Comment: I had no problem getting the table - worked every time I tried. Did not fail once for me for this specific task.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot be sure it will also work from OP's IP :)... nevermind.

Comment: No worries and +1 (for elegance and simplicity if not reliability).

Comment: Thanks Mr Platipus - +1 to you too for your explanation :)